# Join 2 tables with distinct

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `follow` and `following`

**follow**

```
+---------+----------------+
| user_id | follow_user_id |
+---------+----------------+
|       1 |              2 |
|       2 |              3 |
|       3 |              4 |
|     100 |             10 |
+---------+----------------+
```

**following**

```
+---------+-------------------+
| user_id | following_user_id |
+---------+-------------------+
|       1 |                 2 |
|       3 |                 4 |
|       4 |                 6 |
|     200 |               500 |
+---------+-------------------+
```

I want to concat 2 tables without duplicate.

Here is the result that I want.

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+
| user_id | target_user_id |  category |
+---------+----------------+-----------+
|       1 |              2 | follow    |
|       2 |              3 | follow    |
|       3 |              4 | follow    |
|       4 |              6 | following |
|     100 |             10 | follow    |
|     200 |            500 | following |
+---------+----------------+-----------+
```

Condition 1 - Remove duplicated row

Condition 2 - Have to add category column with each table's name

Condition 3 - If category is duplicated, it can be `follow` or `following`. it doesn't matter.

Condition 4 - `follow_user_id` as `target_user_id` and `following_user_id` as `target_user_id`

In this case, should I have to use join? or union?

Any suggestion, very appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Condition 3 - If category is duplicated, it can be follow or following. it doesn't matter."* If follow and following mean the same thing here more or less why do you have two tables? Ideally you should make one table `event` where you have a `event_type_id` which holds `follow` or `following` from a `event_type` table that would make it **alot** more easy to query

Comment: Why do you have two tables?

Comment: I know but it is legacy table and I have to join it to reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `union` and `group by`, the SQL as below:

```
select 
    user_id,target_user_id,min(tag) as category
from 
(
    select user_id,follow_user_id as target_user_id, 'follow' as tag from follow
    union
    select user_id,following_user_id as target_user_id, 'following' as tag from following
) tmp 
group by 
    user_id,target_user_id 
order by 
    user_id,target_user_id;

+---------+----------------+-----------+
| user_id | target_user_id | category  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+
|       1 |              2 | follow    |
|       2 |              3 | follow    |
|       3 |              4 | follow    |
|       4 |              6 | following |
|     100 |             10 | follow    |
|     200 |            500 | following |
+---------+----------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry. I miss some condition. Can you check it again?

Comment: @Hide what does your condition 4 means? follow_user_id as target_user_id and following_user_id as target_user_id

Comment: You know that `follow_user_id` and `following_user_id` column name is different. So I want to combine it to `target_user_id` column.

Comment: @Hide I see you updated your expected result, which is same as my answer result.so what's problem with my answer?

Comment: I updated my question twice. Please refer it. follow and following has different column name(`follow_user_id`, `following_user_id`)

Comment: Original post has same column name. It is my mistake.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!